# C++ functional bind - force cast of `this` to another class possible?

Tags: c++

```
class A {
   public:
   function<void()> myFunc = bind(&A::f, this);

   void f() {
   }
}
```

In a separate `class B` I can point `myFunc` to another function, this time in class B, e.g.

```
class B {
   public:
   B() {
      A* myA = new A();
      myA->myFunc = bind(&B::newFunc, (B*)myA);
   }

   void newFunc() {
   }
}
```

This works just fine, but I have to cast `this` in `newFunc` to `A*` to gain access to the data. Is there any way to force the bind to pass in `this` as an `A*` instead of a `B*`?

I'm guessing not as `bind` requires to cast `myA` to `B*` for it to work in the first place. I suppose what I'm asking goes against the C++ understanding that `this` relates to the class `T` in the function `T::whateverFunc()`.

Comment: If A and B unrelated, you can't. Why need this? Sounds like XY problem...perhaps what you actually could use is cast trick of CRTP - Curiously Recursive Template Pattern.

Comment: You're calling `newFunc` which is a non-static member of `B` against an instance of `A` when there is no relationship between types `A` and `B`.  That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @G.M. if I were to use `reinterpret_cast<B*>(myA)` and then `reinterpret_cast<A*>(this)` I don't think there's a problem because `reinterpret_cast` guarantees you get the original value, so that way would not be undefined (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

Comment: You are fitting a square peg in a round hole. What is your actual problem?

Comment: @PasserBy class `A` has member functions which act on the data in class `A`. These functions are accessed exclusively outside of class `A`. Sometimes these functions need to be changed over time, and this change is to be assigned exclusively outside of `A`.The `bind` and `reinterpret_cast` approach works fine and guarantees data integrity, but as you say it's not ideal.

Comment: You're saying you want to monkey patch a function in `A` with a function defined later on.   You do realize you could `myFunc = [&](){ anything(a); };`?

Comment: @Pixel 2010 already had support for lambdas (i believe MS was one of supporters for the feature). Just no variadic templates and no range-based for

Comment: I don't recall what compiler I was using. Generally quite surprised how C++ has evolved in a decade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create an instance of the class you desire to use or pass it as a paremeter to the function in action.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot exactly understand ***what*** are you trying to do from this code, but there are some cases where you want to add functionality to a class, from **outside** of it. The common way to approach this is by using the [visitor design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

In this case, narrowing casting of `A` into `B` is undefined at best, since this is an invalid casting. Narrowing casting is used when you **know** that an object that *seems* to be `A` is in fact from type `B` if `class A : public B`. Doing the other way around is undefined in any language that I know of.